# awk prints $2 to what I expect, but when I compare $2's value to same it returns false

Tags: awk, ip, ifconfig

When I am giving the following command -

`ip -br -c addr show | awk  '{print $2}'`

It returns something like this output -

```
UNKNOWN
UP
DOWN
UP
UP
UP
UP
```

but when I want to only print the ones which are UP and I say -

`ip -br -c addr show | awk  '$2 == "UP"'`

it does not return anything.
I have used awk with such comparisons and it works, here I am wondering may be `-br` does not return a comparable string. Or is there something I am doing wrong.

Comment: @CarlosPascual, IMHO, that is not working(at least for me when I tested in my Ubuntu 20 test aws box), reason being there are some control characters in output of command.

Comment: @CarlosPascual `UNKNOWN` is not colored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you tell `ip` command to add color codes to your output by using the [`-c` option](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip.8.html):

> **`-c[color][={always|auto|never}`**
>                Configure color output.

Remove `-c`, and `ip -br addr show | awk  '$2 == "UP"'` will work.

Or, you may match the green color code:

```sh
ip -br -c addr show | awk  '$2 == "\033[32mUP"'
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, please try following GNU `grep` code.

```
ip -br -c addr show | grep -oP '^\S+[^A-Z]+UP\D+.*?\K(\d+\.){3}\d+'
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, running `ip -br -c addr show` command and sending its output as standard input to `grep` command. In GNU `grep` code using `oP` options to print only matched values and enable PCRE regex engine. In main program mentioning regex(whose explanation is added below) and printing only matched part.

***Explanation of regex:***

```
^\S+[^A-Z]+UP\D+.*? ##Matching non-spaces from starting of line followed by non-alphabets followed by UP followed by NON-DIGITS(1 or more occurrences) followed by a lazy match of next pattern.
\K                  ##\K will forget the previous matched value and will print only further mentioned regex value.
(\d+\.){3}\d+       ##Matching digits(1 or more occurrences) followed by a dot and matching this group 3 times followed by 1 or more occurrences of digits.
```

Answer (score 2):

The command prints the colors as well, you can see the non printing characters using:

```
ip -br -c addr show | cat -v
```

If you want to keep the color, another option could be using `index()` to check for `UP`

```
ip -br -c addr show | awk  'index($2, "UP")'
```